# Can the PRINCE2 and Scrum Master Certificates be claimed as Contact Hours?

Tags: scrum, pmp, certification, prince2, pdu

My understanding is that a requirement to apply for the Project Management Professional (PMP) certificate is to accumulate **35 Contact Hours** (also referred as PDUs by other sources) prior to the application. Check this reference video [**here**](http://www.projectsmart.co.uk/forums/viewtopic.php?t=1085&p=1429#p1429&utm_source=twitterfeed&utm_medium=twitter).

I was hoping to confirm whether you can claim the PRINCE2 Training (Foundation and Practitioner certificates) and Scrum Master Certificate as Contact Hours since both trainings have not been gained via the Project Management Institute (PMI). Does that really matter?

There are several supportive questions in the Site about PMP and its requirements but I haven't found references to specific certificates and their conversion into Contact Hours.

Does anybody have any guidelines to follow? *How have you claimed your Contact/PDU Hours prior to  your PMP application?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am absolutely sure that a [PMI Customer Care](http://www.pmi.org/About-Us/Customer-Care/Contact-Us-Form.aspx) person would be able to answer this in a second, but I'm not one.  However, I did a little investigation using the PMI search engine for [courses offered through Registered Education Providers](https://ccrs.pmi.org/) and found over 150 courses having to do with PRINCE2.  This leads me to believe that PRINCE2 training absolutely counts...but *how* you show that is going to depend on where you took your training classes.

In other words, I don't think you would be able to say "I have the PRINCE2 Foundation and Practitioner certificates and get *automatic* credit (that's what Customer Care could probably clarify right away), but you *can* say "I took a PRINCE2 Foundation and Practitioner course from PROVIDERNAME" and if that provider is a PMI provider you'll get credit for the equivalent number of hours (some are 35, some are 59, etc -- depends on the course).

Comment: +1 - @jcmeloni for the reference to the courses search engine, really useful.